# override css div display: none;

Tags: html, css

Thanks for your time! The codes are very simple. I suppose it should display "This is CPU". But it didn't. Where am I wrong?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keegoo/8ccbcyxc/)

For people who cannot open Fiddle, here's the codes:

HTML:

```
<div id="tab1" class="active" ><p>This is CPU</p></div>
<div id="tab2"><p>This is MEM</p></div>
<div id="tab3"><p>This is Network IO Receive</p></div>
<div id="tab4"><p>This is Network IO Send</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4 {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

By add `!important` it do works. But why if I changes all the ids to classes, it could work?

e.g.: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keegoo/8qk0dzvn/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/8ccbcyxc/2/

Comment: Using `!important` will force the `display: block`. [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ccbcyxc/1/)

Comment: @Pugazh, but why if I changed all the ids to classes, it could work?

Comment: @user1476512 let me know if my answer helps

Comment: @Quentin, m sorry but sometimes according to condition we have to use !important and we can use it separately so it won't affect other css rules..isn't it ok??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major thing to note here is the **CSS priorities**

In this scenario the **Rule provided using Id will have more priority over the class**

You need to **use combination of your id and class to create a even more priority than just the id**

```
#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4 {
  display: none;
}

#tab1.active , #tab2.active , #tab3.active , #tab4.active {
  display: block;
}
```

You can also use partial selectors to reduce the code..

```
[id^=tab].active{
 display: block;
}
```

**Note :** Do not use `!important` unless you have no other option left. In most of the cases the work can be done without using`!important`at all.

Comment: @user1476512 glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Use `important` here.

```
.active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Css id selector `#` has high priority so to make active work you need to use `!important`. However, i'll prefer to use the following way:

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab active" id="tab1"><p>This is CPU</p></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2"><p>This is MEM</p></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab3"><p>This is Network IO Receive</p></div>
<div class="tab" id="tab4"><p>This is Network IO Send</p></div>
```